# Affinity Designer for Windows: How to use scientific and mathematical expressions (e.g. Latex)?

Tags: affinity-designer, latex, mathematics

Title says it all, is there a way to directly write math equations in AD?

Comment: I *think* this might be the sort of question which is best suited to Affinity Designer's forums or even their tech support folks... I know a lot of folks over there in Affnity's direct fora have discussed how to bring in equations from LayTex, LayTexIT, Formulator and a slew of other such tools, but I don't *think* we here at **GDSE** should be stepping into a tech support for software XX role.

Comment: There's an online LaTeX Preview service which can generate an SVG. http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/ - You can use the SVG generated in any vector image editor that can open or import SVGs.

Comment: Yes I have used this - https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Answer (score 0):

Nope - but there are a good half dozen threads on this topic in the Affinity Designer forums, with some really good answers around Latex LatexIt, and other solutions.